# Querying deep nested json value from postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I would like to count distinct values from **someText** property from nested jbson object, but I can't figure out how properly do it. Any suggestions are appreciated.

This is my jbson object

```
{ options: [    
        {
            "object": { "someText": "example1"}
        },
        {
            "object": { "someText": "example2"}
        },
        {
            "object": { "someText": "example3"}
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct option_tb) AS uniqueOptions FROM tableT
WHERE option_tb->'options'->0 IS NOT NULL
AND option_tb->'options'->>'object'-> 'someText' is not null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use set-returning [`jsonb_path_query()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.19.1.1.1):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(distinct v) AS uniqueOptions FROM tableT,
jsonb_path_query(option_tb,'$.options[*].object.someText?(@!=null)') as _(v);
```

This produces implicit lateral join with your table, each `option_tb` spawning one row per match found by the function. No match means no rows returned. You will end up counting all possible distinct values of `someText` in all rows. This also doesn't mind varying jsonb structures with missing elements in some rows: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/WNzr8duh)

```sql
create table tableT (option_tb jsonb);
insert into tableT values
('{ "options": [ {"object": { "someText": "example1"}},
                 {"object": { "someText": "example2"}},
                 {"object": { "someText": "example3"}},
                 {"object": { "someText": null}}      ]}'),
('{ "options": [ {"object": {"someText": "example4"}} ]}'),
('{ "options": [ {"differentObject": { }            } ]}'),
('{ "options": []}'), ('{ "options": {}}'),
('{ "options": "hello"}'), ('{ "notEvenOptions": 1}'),
('[]'),('{}'),('1'),('"a"'),('false'),('"null"'),('null'),(null);

SELECT COUNT(distinct v) AS uniqueOptions,array_agg(distinct v) FROM tableT,
jsonb_path_query(option_tb,'$.options[*].object.someText?(@!=null)') as _(v);
```

| uniqueoptions | array_agg |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | {""example1"",""example2"",""example3"",""example4""} |

Note that null comparison in [JSONPath](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) expressions works differently from plain SQL: in SQL `v=null` yields `null` regardless of the `v` value. In JSONPath, it works like `v is null`.

---

To get the same result in versions 9.4 to 11 that didn't yet support JSONPath expressions, with a bit of care you can use [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE), similar to what [@SelVazi suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77323469/5298879): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/45rPOitS)

```sql
SELECT count(distinct v) AS uniqueOptions, array_agg(v) FROM (
    SELECT v#>'{object,someText}' AS v FROM tableT,
    jsonb_array_elements( case when 'array'=jsonb_typeof(option_tb->'options')
                          then option_tb->'options'
                          else '[]'::jsonb end) as _(v) 
) as _(v) WHERE jsonb_typeof(v)<>'null';
```

It's good to remember that your `tableT` is actually `tablet`, unless you [double-quote](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) it.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried the code above, but I getting an error: [42883] ERROR: function jsonb_path_query(product, unknown) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you on? This the JSONPath support was added in version 12. The oldest supported version is 11, and its support ends 3 weeks from now: [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Comment: Zegarek, thank you very much. The issue was with the version - 11 in my case. The first answer with jsonb_path_query() works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jsonb_array_elements()` function to turn a JSON array into rows :

```
select option_tb, count(opt->'object'->'someText')
from tableT
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(tableT.option_tb->'options') AS opt
group by option_tb
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ayRD2v-O)

Comment: Selvazi, thank you. This also works, but it's a bit slow copare with @ Zegarek answer. The is is probably the use of cross join.

Answer (score -1):

Simply you can use operators and functions to achieve this for example:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT option_tb->>'someText') AS uniqueOptions
FROM tableT
WHERE option_tb->'options' IS NOT NULL;
```